# React autocomplete get object onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, autocomplete

Upon the `onchange` event below, I need to get a vehicle object.  Instead, I am getting only a vehicle number which got displayed as dropdown value. I tried to pass item to get vehicle object, but still I am getting a vehicle number.

**My onchange listener:**

```
onChange={(event, item) => handleVehicleChange(event, item)}
```

**My autocomplete element:**

```
<div className="autocomplete-wrapper">
<label htmlFor="title">Vehilce No</label>
<Autocomplete
    placeholder="please select vehicle"
    value={vehicle.val}
    items={vehicles}
    getItemValue={item => item.number}
    shouldItemRender={renderVehicleNumber}
    renderMenu={item => (
    <div className="dropdown">
        {item}
    </div>
    )}  
    renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) =>
    <div className={`item ${isHighlighted ? 'selected-item' : ''}`}>
        {item.numberPlate}
    </div>
    }
    onChange={(event, vehicle) => handleVehicleChange(event, vehicle)}
    onSelect={vehicle => handleVehicleChange('',  vehicle)}
/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn’t it accessible inside event? ....event.target maybe?

Comment: event.target is not working

Answer (score 0):

Should it be vehicle.val? Rather than vehicle inside your element?